# The ambiguity of: see / hear / listen to news

Tags: meaning, synonyms, ambiguity

When you google "hear", "listen", "watch", or  "see" , many links appear telling the differences between them, but I wanted to see if the same applies to "news" or not.

The difference in meaning is obvious with the following:

> Watch news = watching news on TV
>   Read news = reading a newspaper

But I am not 100% sure about these:

> See the news

Are we watching television or reading a paper?

> Listen to news

I understand that expression is commonly used when we listen to the radio. But can we say the same thing when we listen to the TV anchorman without looking at the screen?

> Hear the news

Do we use this when somebody tells us some news?
What about radio or TV (without looking at the screen)?

Comment: The first thing that needs addressing is article usage and different senses of the word 'news'. 'Have you heard the news?' uses the definite article to specify 'the salient item/s of news that concern us'. But 'I want to watch the news' means you want to watch a news programme. // 'Did you see the news?' implies that the questioner thinks it more probable that you came across the salient news via a visual medium, probably television (if at all). But it could also be asking whether you caught the news programme. / 'I listened to the television news rather than watching it' would be normally ...

Comment: used to disambiguate, this being an unusual scenario. 'I listened to the news' would normally be taken to refer to listening to the news on the radio (the speaker being normally sighted). / 'I heard the news' would normally be taken as just a paraphrase of 'I became aware of the news' without further context.

Comment: Antonio, do me a favor.  Take a look at one or more dictionaries and then rewrite your question if there's something specific there that you would like clarified.  Whole teams of experts have already written a lot of helpful stuff, including examples.  It's amazing how much one can get from dictionaries.  Try looking up the verbs themselves and also "news."  But do come back and ask here (or at English Language Learners) if there's anything that's still not clear to you.

Comment: You need to always add "the"  in front of *news*. It's difficult to know if you sometimes forgot or you didn't know that we always say "the news".

Comment: In particular, "hear" can be quite ambiguous in terms of the possible mode of communication.  "Did you hear the news?" is quite idiomatic for for asking "Are you aware of this?", for instance.

Comment: I suggest your Question does not belong here but rather, somewhere such as English Language Learners.

If you think that's not fair, please explain why?

Answer (score -1):

Literally, "see" the news can't distinguish between print and screen;
"listen to" and "hear" can't tell radio or TV from gossip…

Idiomatically, "see…" and "hear…" both mean "notice/somehow become aware of"